# As imported data from the site, via IMPORTXML

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

There is a website on which products are presented.
I wanted to import all products with prices and articles into a Google table via IMPORT XML.
But it turned out so far only to collect all possible pages in a separate column `E:E` (`=IMPORTXML("https://dg-trade.ru/catalog/";"//li[@class='sect']/a/@href" )`)
The problem arises due to the fact that not all products on the page are shown on the site, and they need to be loaded as they scroll. How can this be circumvented?
As a result, I would like to get a table like on sheet 2.
Link to the table: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rD8jJujaAe9Yz2uBB_4IMTcUs_oQFrF88ydmEIiXCsg/edit?usp=sharing
The table will be like this (for example, line 5 on sheet 1):

| Name | Qty | Art | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Масло моторное LUKOIL AVANTGARDE ULTRA 15W-40 (на розлив) | Много | 4001/1703 | 760 руб./л. |
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your expected values. Can I ask you about the detail of your expected values?

Comment: Here , rather, I'm not so good with English :(
I want to get a table in which there will be all the products uploaded from the site by columns, as in the table in the question.
So that you can then easily work with this table

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.